# How do I use Neo4j-embedded for Python (threads) in Flask microframework?

Tags: python, flask, neo4j

I'm following the Flask Tutorial (Flaskr) in order to experiment with using Neo4j-embedded for Python. This is in a virtualenv. Here is my 'main' app code:

```
import os
import jpype
from neo4j import GraphDatabase
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, render_template, flash

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])


def connectDB(): 
    return GraphDatabase(app.config['DATABASE'])


def initDB():
    db = connectDB()

    with db.transaction:
        users = db.node()
        roles = db.node()

        db.reference_node.USERS(users)
        db.reference_node.ROLES(roles)

        userIndex = db.node.indexes.create('users')

        user = db.node(name=app.config['ADMIN'])
        user.INSTANCE_OF(users)
        userIndex['name'][app.config['ADMIN']] = user

        role = db.node(type='superadmin')
        role.INSTANCE_OF(roles)

        role.ASSIGN_TO(user)

    db.shutdown()

    print "Database initialized."


def testDB():
    db = connectDB()

    with db.transaction:
        userIndex = db.node.indexes.get('users')
        user = userIndex['name'][app.config['ADMIN']].single
        username = user['name']

    db.shutdown()

    print "Admin username is '%s'. Database exists." % username


@app.before_request
def before_request():
    jpype.attachThreadToJVM()
    g.db = connectDB()


@app.teardown_request
def teardown_request(exception):
    g.db.shutdown()


@app.route('/')
def index():

    with g.db.transaction:
        userIndex = g.db.node.indexes.get('users')
        user = userIndex['name'][app.config['ADMIN']].single
        username = user['name']

    fields = dict(username=username)
    return render_template('index.html', fields=fields)


if os.path.exists(app.config['DATABASE']) == False:
    initDB()
else:
    testDB()
```

initDB() and testDB() work perfectly fine - without Gremlin, PyLucene, etc. - just jpype and neo4j-embedded. Initially, the JVM would fail and the app would terminate when I would request index().  I scoured the net to learn that I needed to add the line "jpype.attachThreadToJVM()" into before_request() to solve that issue with python threading the JVM and the app does not terminate. However, this leads immediately to another issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/ht/dev/envFlask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/ht/dev/envFlask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1506, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/ht/dev/envFlask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1504, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/ht/dev/envFlask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1264, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/ht/dev/envFlask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1262, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/ht/dev/envFlask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1248, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/ht/dev/apps/evobox/evobox/__init__.py", line 68, in index
    userIndex = g.db.node.indexes.get('users')
  File "/ht/dev/envFlask/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4j/index.py", line 36, in get
    return self._index.forNodes(name)
java.lang.RuntimeExceptionPyRaisable: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No index provider 'lucene' found. Maybe the intended provider (or one more of its dependencies) aren't on the classpath or it failed to load.
```

Google search of the entire last line didn't go anywhere. Just searching "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No index provider 'lucene' found." lead to nothing in the context of python.

The neo4j messages.log seems to show the database was opened 3 times (initDB(), testDB(), and index()). The classpath is the same for each instance:

```
Class Path: /ht/dev/envFlask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4j/javalib/neo4j-jmx-1.5.M02.jar:/ht/dev/envFlask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4j/javalib/neo4j-lucene-index-1.5.M02.jar:/ht/dev/envFlask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4j/javalib/neo4j-graph-matching-1.5.M02.jar:/ht/dev/envFlask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4j/javalib/neo4j-1.5.M02.jar:/ht/dev/envFlask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4j/javalib/neo4j-kernel-1.5.M02.jar:/ht/dev/envFlask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4j/javalib/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar:/ht/dev/envFlask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4j/javalib/lucene-core-3.1.0.jar:/ht/dev/envFlask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4j/javalib/neo4j-graph-algo-1.5.M02.jar:/ht/dev/envFlask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4j/javalib/neo4j-udc-1.5.M02.jar:/ht/dev/envFlask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4j/javalib/neo4j-cypher-1.5.M02.jar:/ht/dev/envFlask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4j/javalib/scala-library-2.9.0-1.jar
```

I also modified index() to connectDB and attachThreadToJVM directly like initDB() and testDB() without using the 'g' global - this resulted in exact same error.

What am I possibly missing/overlooking to get neo4j-embedded and jpype working on a threaded request and not just in the 'main' app?

Note: I'm aware of the RESTful Web Service solutions with py2neo or Rexster/Bulbs, but I want avoid that for now.

EDIT: Using JPype-0.5.4.2, Neo4j-embedded-1.5.b2, Java-6-openjdk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One issue with this pattern is that you run the risk of starting multiple databases pointed at the same location, which will lead to problems. What you would want is a single instance of the database that follows the full lifecycle of your application.

Why it's not finding the lucene provider is a harder question.. The index provider is loaded using java service loader, which means that JPype should not affect it. As long as the JVM start alright, and the lucene-index implementation jar is on the classpath, it should work.

It may be related to threading somehow, I'm currently writing a fix to automaitcally handle the "attachThreadToJVM()" calls. I'll add a test case to make sure reading indexes from a separate thread works as expected as well.

The threading work is currently kept updated in this mailing list thread:

http://neo4j-community-discussions.438527.n3.nabble.com/Neo4j-Python-embedding-problems-with-shutdown-and-threads-td3476163.html

Comment: thanks for the link to mailing list thread; I see there is an update. I'll try a different pattern as well.

Comment: It was the pattern! I was using the pattern according to Flask's tutorial (written for SQLite). Doing shutdown() after every transaction and reconnecting for new transactions was the problem. I now just connect once. I used a script (atexit) from a response in the mailing list to ensure the shutdown is proper.

Answer (score 3):

Tried replicating the error, using a clean install of neo4j, flask , and jpipe, using the standard java default path. Could not produce that log.
But I got an error of

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "teststack.py", line 27, in initDB
    userIndex = db.node.indexes.create('users')
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neo4j/index.py", line 32, in create
   return self._index.forNodes(name, to_java(config))
 jpype._jexception.RuntimeExceptionPyRaisable: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:      Supplied index configuration:
{}
doesn't match stored config in a valid way:
{provider=lucene, type=exact}
for 'users'
```

when using `initDB`

fixed with

```
userIndex = db.node.indexes.create(users)
```

Comment: I created a new venv, rebuilt Jpype against java-6-openjdk, and did a clean install and still getting same error.  Could you elaborate on what you mean by 'standard java default path'? 

I have set JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk. 

In the meantime, I'm going to see if an older version of JPype will make a difference.